# How to speed up prysm sync?

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization, prysm

I am using `prysm` as consensus client to sync; however, it is taking a while to sync from genesis. Is there a way to speed up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `checkpoint` feature of [`prysm`](https://docs.prylabs.network/docs/prysm-usage/checkpoint-sync) speed up sync. It is essentially a way to get the state (`checkpoint`) from a trusted source instead of starting syncing from the genesis node.

> If you can’t get the state from your own node, you’ll have to get it from someone else. A friend or family member you trust that runs their own node would be an excellent source. This isn’t trustless but will usually still have a very high level of trust, even without further verification.

Here is a [list](https://eth-clients.github.io/checkpoint-sync-endpoints/#mainnet) of publicly available nodes you can use and sync quickly.

Comment: I'm getting problems with sync after restart all (validator, geth and beacon) in my private blockchain. Its not sync anymore. How can I have a checkpoint server local ?