# Geth does not sync - Proof of Stake

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization, eth-2.0, prysm

I am trying to run full node on Ethereum mainnet; however, I believe geth doesn't sync. I started the GETH client with

`geth --ws --http --http.api eth,net,engine,admin,txpool --authrpc.jwtsecret jwt.hex`

Despite multiple attempts, it prints looking for peers for 2-3 times but then stops printing any information.

All I see is, `beacon client online, but never received consensus updates. Please ensure your beacon client is operational to follow the chain!`

I connected the consensus client and it is syncing but not the geth client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `geth` client will not start `sync` before your `consensus-client` does not sync completely. If you are using `prysm` consensus client, you can use [`checkpoint`](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/136748/how-to-speed-up-prysm-sync) sync feature to sync in minutes so you don't need to wait.

This is also verified by `go-ethereum` team in this [issue](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/25911).

Answer (score 0):

hi been waiting a few days to snyc and it written CC fully sync but Ec still 0.00% and not moving , anybody can help ?